# How to integrate mysql database to a AWS AMPLIFY REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Im trying to connect my MySql database to a rest API, but the documentation always shows that I have to add a Graphql mutation to be able to work. Is there any way I can use only MySql?

Comment: You could set up Lambda functions to make the request to the MySql database.